# Disable mouse dragging item on Storyboard designer

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

There are some overlapping items, let's say A and B. To be specific, A is a background image. On other GUI frameworks, setting a background image is easy, but it seems I have to place an ImageView to fill the view with a background image on the Storyboard.

When I am trying to drag B, often A is selected and moved. Can I "lock" A so that it will not move? I searched the web and found that on Document --> Lock, but setting it to "Localizable Properties" does not lock it. I could still drag it with mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to set Lock to All Properties. You can still select the object, and click+drag will move it -- but it snaps back into place when you release it.

Unfortunately, this locks - as expected - **ALL** properties, so you could not, for example, lock a label in-place while also editing its content.